# Login Process Variable Not Set

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, authentication

So I am having issues at current with my login page where I am trying to get the login process to return a variable so I can display a error code on my login page but cannot see where I am going wrong...

**PHP Error when typing wrong login credentials**

`Notice: Undefined variable: output in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\reveal\store\qadmin\login\login.process.php on line 27`

**Login Form**

```
<div class="widget-body">

    <!-- Form -->
<?php

    if(isset ($loginerror)) {

        ?>

            <div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
                <span style="padding-bottom: 10px; color:red;">Successfully Logged Out</span>
            </div>

        <?php

    } else {

    ?>

        <span>Either No Login Data or something is horribly wrong.</span><br /><br />

    <?php

    };

?>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <label>Username or Email</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Your Username or Email address"/> 
    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="input-block-level margin-none" placeholder="Your Password" />
    <div class="separator bottom"></div> 
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="uniformjs"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4 center">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-inverse" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- // Form END -->
```

**Index.php**

```
session_start(); 

global $error;

// Simple check if the user is logged in or not
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include("login.process.php");

    $checkUser = login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

    if ($checkUser == "No") {


        $error = "true";

    } else if (is_array($checkUser)) {

        $_SESSION['user'] = $checkUser;
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

    }
}

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {

    include ("home.php");

}

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    include ("login.php");
}
```

**Login.process.php**

```
function login($username, $password) {

            include("../config.php");

            // Open up a new MySQLi connection to the MySQL database
            mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
            mysql_select_db($dbTable);

            // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)

            $username1 = stripslashes($username);
            $password1 = stripslashes($password);
            $username2 = mysql_real_escape_string($username1);
            $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($password1);
            $password3 = md5($password2);
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username2' AND password='$password3'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            if ($result > 0) {

                while($logincheck = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $output = array('username' => $username2, 'uid' => $logincheck['id'], 'superadmin' => $logincheck['superadmin']);
                };

                return $output;

            } else {

                $loginerror = "Login Error";
                return $loginerror;

            };
}
```

I am probably doing something stupid but cannot work out why it is returning that error!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So may be for some reason your query does not work and therefore never set `$output`

All you need to do is to set your `$output` before the loop, so in case if you loop doesn't works you have `$output` already set as an `array()`

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $output = array(); // here is the trick

    while($logincheck = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output = array('username' => $username2, 'uid' => $logincheck['id'], 'superadmin' => $logincheck['superadmin']);
    };

    return $output;

} else {

    $loginerror = "Login Error";
    return $loginerror;

};
```

Comment: the problem with that is that now the output is set it logs in with no session set for the username, the group etc... The $logincheck still does not appear to take place?

Comment: you need to use `mysql_num_rows($result) > 0` instead of `$result > 0`

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because there is not any record on your table when have wrong login credentials.
So Just change your if condition to count number of rows in result to remove the error. `Login.process.php`

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

Instead of:

```
if ($result > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function login($username, $password) {

            include("../config.php");

            // Open up a new MySQLi connection to the MySQL database
            mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
            mysql_select_db($dbTable);

            // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)

            $username1 = stripslashes($username);
            $password1 = stripslashes($password);
            $username2 = mysql_real_escape_string($username1);
            $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($password1);
            $password3 = md5($password2);
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username2' AND password='$password3'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            if ($result > 0) {

$output=array();
                while($logincheck = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $output = array('username' => $username2, 'uid' => $logincheck['id'], 'superadmin' => $logincheck['superadmin']);
                };

                return $output;

            } else {

                $loginerror = "Login Error";
                return $loginerror;

            };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Process of login

```
public function index()
{   
if($this->input->post())
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password', 'Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $post=$this->input->post();
            $clean = $this->security->xss_clean($post);
            $check=$this->CM->userAuthentication($clean);
             if($check!='success')
              { 
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',array('message'=> "$check",'class' =>'alert alert-danger'));
                redirect('login');
              }else
                {
                    redirect('dashboard');
                }
        }else
        {
            $this->load->view('sign-in');
        }
    }else
    {
        $this->load->view('sign-in');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? Which parts are needed to solve the problem?